# Relating solutions of differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider two second order differential operators $D_1$ and $D_2$ in variables $x$ and $y$ respectively. Given two eigenfunctions $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ with eigenvalues $e_1$ and $e_2$ respectively:

$$D_1\psi_1(x)=e_1\psi_1(x)\\D_2\psi_2(y)=e_2\psi_2(y)$$

and the relation

$$D_1 K(x,y)=D_2 K(x,y)\neq0$$

with a known non-trivial function $K(x,y)$, there should be a way to obtain $\psi_1(x)$ from $\psi_2(y)$ and $K(x,y)$ via an integration in $y$ assuming the same boundary conditions for both eigenfunctions. How to set up this relation explicitly?

Comment: What if $K(x,y)= 0$? The relation holds trivially, and you can not anything about $D_1$ and $D_2$.

Comment: I am referring to cases with non-trivial $K(x,y)$. I will edit the question to emphasize that.

Comment: The problem still occurs if you have a $K$ which is mapped to zero by both operators. For example $K(x,y) = x + y$, and $D_1 = \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2}$ and $D_2=\sin(y) \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial y^2}$.

Comment: Good point! By saying that $K(x,y)$ is non-trivial we should also exclude these cases.

Comment: Ok, but $D_1 - D_2$ is also a second order differential operator. So if both $D_1$ and $D_2$ are linear, you will always have two dimensions of $K$ which fullfil the requirement. Thus, I don't think that one can say something about obtaining $\psi_1$ from $\psi_2$ in general.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "two dimensions of $K$"? Note that $D_1$ and $D_2$ act on different spaces parametrized by $x$ and $y$ respectively, so I am not sure how and why you suggest to subtract them.

Comment: I guess you mean that one can define a two dimensional differential operator $D=D_1-D_2$ so that $K$ would be an eigenfunction with eigenvalue zero $D K=0$. So there might be several $K$ that satisfy this equation? But note that there are boundary conditions implied, which make $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ as well as $K$ unique.